# Cross Apply vs "comma Join"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, cross-apply

I had a co-worker that loved using what she referred to as a "comma join". I have recently used cross apply for the first time ever in a live environment and noticed that it gave the same result as her "comma join" and was wondering if there was something different about the two or if her way was just short hand. below I have code that makes two temp tables and then it does a cross apply to attach everything in the first temp table to everything in the second. It also does this with her "comma join".

```
Select
    'a' as a,'b' as b,'c' as c,'d' as d
Into #letter


Create table #name
( name  varchar(10))

Insert Into #Name
Values('David'),('Kai'),('Brad'),('Todd'),('Vivian')



Select *
From #Name
Cross apply(Select * from #letter) as A

Select *
    From #name
    ,#letter
```

So are these the same just different way to write it or does it do something different in some cases? Oh we use SQL 2012.

Comment: the "comma join" is the old-style join. [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Comma Joins... Yuck.  Here's a link that references Oracle but same thing... get out of that syntax.  Comma Joins are just bad practice and make it hard to read.  They do still have some handy use cases but for the most part they are ugly and annoying to have to sift thru the Filters aka WHERE clause to locate all of the JOINs. http://www.orafaq.com/node/2618

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These "comma joins" are, as SqlZim pointed out, an old-style way of joining tables called implicit join.
The join condition for this kind of join is in the where clause - for example -

```
SELECT *
FROM a, b
WHERE a.Id = b.aId
```

Is the same as

```
SELECT *
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.Id = b.aId
```

For what I hope is obvious reasons, implicit (or old style) joins are frowned upon - as you can probably easily imagine, when you need to join more than two tables it becomes very unreadable compared to explicit joins.

[`Cross apply`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx), however, is not a join at all.
What `Cross apply` means is you execute whatever is on the right side of the `cross apply` operator for each row on the left side.

A more accurate explicit join for the implicit join statement you posted would be

```
SELECT *
FROM #name
CROSS JOIN #letter
```

Another option would be to use an inner join with a join condition that will always evaluate to `true` - like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM #name
INNER JOIN #letter ON 1=1
```